# How can I unzip a file and upload individually all its file to s3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, zip, unzip

This is mainly a syntactical question that I can't seem to wrap my hands around.

This is what I have now :

```
    Zip::ZipFile.open(zipped_file, Zip::ZipFile::CREATE) do |zipfile|
      zipfile.each do |file|

        config = YAML.load_file(Rails.root + 'config/s3/s3.yml')[Rails.env]
        AWS.config config # instantiate AWS creds..

        # @filepath = .. I can't figure this out. How do I get a file and file path from a Zip::ZipEntry or ZipFile object to be able to upload a File object to S3..

        AWS.s3.buckets[config['bucket']].objects.create("quizzes/" + v['id'] + "/" + file.to_s, file: @filepath )
```

Suggestions, tips, ideas? Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

The snippet you posted is actually creating a zip file instead of unzipping an archive. The [documentation](http://rubyzip.sourceforge.net/classes/Zip/ZipFileSystem.html) has an example on extracting an archive.

For files, check out [ZipFsFile](http://rubyzip.sourceforge.net/classes/Zip/ZipFileSystem/ZipFsFile.html) and for directories, [ZipFsDIr](http://rubyzip.sourceforge.net/classes/Zip/ZipFileSystem/ZipFsDir.html). Alternatively, you could specify your own directory so that it's not in the application's directory.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hmm... fair enough. If it is in fact creating a zipFile in my snippet, it *does* give me access to read the files inside the zip file.. How could I just read the files without creating a new zip file?

Comment: It's in the documentation example linked above, under 'Reading is as easy as writing...`

Comment: The example does this : `puts zipfile.file.read("first.txt")`, which prints the content of the file. But I need it to be a File object *I think* so I can upload it s3..

Comment: Hmm.. also it seems like an uncessary step to extract its string detail and then reconvert it into a file.. shouldn't it be a file originally that I can without writing it to my local disk, access, and then upload to s3? thanks for your help by the way.. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Ok so this is what I did :

```
# zipped_file = the file in my params[:attachment]

file_list = Zip::ZipFile.open(zipped_file)
file_list.each do |file|
  filename = file.name
  basename = File.basename(filename)

  tempfile = Tempfile.new(basename)
  tempfile.binmode
  tempfile.write file.get_input_stream.read            

  s3_obj = bucket.objects[ 'attachments/' + filename ]
  s3_obj.write(tempfile)
end
```